# Does SQL Server support the Poisson distribution?

Tags: predictive-modeling, databases, sql, programming, distribution

I am trying to do some work that is primarily based in SQL Server. I cannot seem to find a native function to SQL that supports the Poisson distribution. Has anyone had success with applying Poisson natively within SQL?

Comment: I am super curious as to the reason you wish to apply the Poisson distribution in a query. Can you elaborate.

Comment: Do you want the CDF, the PDF, samples from it?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, SQL Server does support it, as a part of [Data Analysis Expressions (DAX)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_analysis_expressions).

The documentation for the function for getting Poisson distribution data is [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt171492.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that someone has managed to implement a Poisson sampling in SQL Server. Checkout this link: http://bilquist.com/poisson-sampling-in-sql/